# Solving for current in a circuit problem (image included)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I need to find $I_{R_2}$ and I need someone to explain why $I_T = I_{R_1} = 1 mA$. I thought that we were supposed to use the fact that $I_T = I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} + I_{R_3}$:

[image]

I have solved for $R_T = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{6}} + 6 = 10 k \Omega$

I'm in the Navy as an E-3 and we don't have any real instructors, everything is computer based training, so I appreciate an explanation based response.

Comment: If you need more background information, or a better forum for electronics, go here: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were given the current through $R_1$ as 1mA. You should know that the 1mA current is shared between $R_2$ and $R_3$. You could determine the voltage drop across $R_1$, and then $R_{eq}$ (the equivalence of $R_2$ and $R_3$) so you can calculate the current through each resistor.

Added:
Yes, the voltage drop across $R_1$ is 6V. Remember that this circuit has a parallel portion and a serial portion. $R_1$ is in series with $R_{eq}$, so we have 6kΩ and $R_{eq}$. $R_2$ and $R_3$ are in parallel, so the equivalent resistance is the inverse of the sum of the inverse of the resistances. Well, that is difficult to interpret.

Lets start with current: $I_T=I_{R1}+I_{R2}$.
Substituting V=IR, we get: $V/R_T=V/R_2+V/R_3$.
Since the voltage is the same: $1/R_T=1/R_2+1/R_3$.
$R_T$ is the same as $R_{eq}$.
Inverting both sides gives: $R_{eq}=\frac {1}{1/R_2+1/R_3}$.
Plugging in the numbers is $R_{eq}=\frac {1}{1/12+1/6}kΩ \rightarrow = \frac {1}{1/12+2/12}kΩ \rightarrow = \frac {1}{3/12}kΩ \rightarrow = \frac {12}{3}kΩ \rightarrow = 4kΩ$.

Comment: Could you explain how to get $R_{eq}$? and I'm not sure what you mean by "determining the voltage drop across $R_{1}$" - You talking about $V_{R_1} = IR = (1 mA)(6 k) = 6$?

Comment: What I don't understand is why are saying that $R_{eq} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12}} = 4$ instead of using the value $10$.